# code in node js lambda: get the lastmodified date of the s3 key from event data

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am using the node js code inside the lambda. A function
passes event data when an S3 object created

```
var record = event.Records[0];
var bucket = record.s3.bucket.name;
var key = record.s3.object.key;
```

How can i get the last modified date of the s3 key to create a folder and paste the key in it.

If the Last Modified date is: `Mon Feb 22 14:46:23 GMT+530 2016`,

then folder name must be: `Bucketname/2016/02/22/`

Answer (score 7):

You have to send an HTTP Head Request

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'})   

var params = {
   Bucket: record.s3.bucket.name,
   Key : record.s3.object.key
};

s3.headObject(params, function (error, response) {
   if(error) {
      context.fail();
   } else {
       var date = response.LastModified; //Last modified date
       context.done(null,date);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The [event structure](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-content-structure.html) doesn't actually contain the last-modified value for the object.

You could send an http `HEAD` request for the object, or -- probably -- use the value of `Records[0].eventTime`.  The documentation isn't thoroughly clear that this will always be the same, saying only that it's "when S3 finished processing the request."

Comment: Records[0].eventTime is providing  : "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z" please guide me  to send a HEAD request.

Comment: That's strange,  You can send a `HEAD` request to S3 from node using [`headObject()` in the AWS SDK for Javascript](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#headObject-property).  `data.LastModified` should contain the last modified timestamp of the current version of the object.